# highcharts does not seem to be rendering

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

I am following this example 
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/pie-chart
I want to display highcharts through retrieving data from the database. My pie highcharts is not displaying though I am not getting any error. I am retrieving data from database mysql. here is my code

```js
         $(document).ready(function() {
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container2',
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'diseas Per area'
                    },
                    // tooltip: {
                        // formatter: function() {
                            // return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.y+ 'd Count';
                        // }
                    // },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                color: '#000000',
                                connectorColor: '#000000',
                                formatter: function() {
                                    return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.y;
                                }
                            },
                            showInLegend: true
                        }
                    },
                    series: []
                };

                $.getJSON("fcount.php", function(json) {
                    options.series = json;
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
            });
```

```css
<div id="container2" style="height: 550px; min-width: 310px; max-width:800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

kindly tell me what I am doing wrong. It does not show any error but still it does not display

my php code is

```js
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `Area` AS Zone, COUNT( `Diease` ) AS problem FROM table  GROUP BY `Area` ");

//$rows = array();
$rows['type'] = 'pie';
$rows['name'] = 'Diease Count';
//$rows['innerSize'] = '50%';
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows['data'][] = array('zone '.$r['area'].'"', $r['problem']);    
}
$rslt = array();
array_push($rslt,$rows);
print json_encode($rslt, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: I notice your Highcharts code stating `series: []`. This means your data is always an empty array.

Comment: i am retrieving data from database . i have also given my php file

Comment: Could you post an example of how your `series` array (or what is in your `var json`) is looking? I think that is where the problem lays

Answer (score 0):

instead of push array into an empty array like this

```
$rslt = array();
array_push($rslt,$rows);
print json_encode($rslt, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

use it like below

```
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Haider. but still my charts does not display

Answer (score 0):

The lack of data is probably caused by the format of your `options.series`. When using a pie chart, your `series` should be formatted like this:

```
options.series = [{ name: 'Browsers', 
                   data: [ ["Firefox",60] , ["Chrome",40]]
                 }]
```

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ogrjhqfn/12/) JSFiddle I used your options code to generate the chart. So if your `options.series` looks like shown above, the chart should work.